# XNA 4.0 thick triangle strip to fix aliasing issues upon rotation

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, antialiasing, gl-triangle-strip

My triangle strip based lines are disappearing intermittently when I rotate my camera around the X axis.

I was advised that this is due to aliasing issues and that "At a certain angle when its edge is facing the camera your strip will disappear." So, I was told to give the strip some thickness.

Can someone tell me the best way to do this? Would it be to draw two strips directly on top of each other? This doesn't seem to solve the problem but perhaps I am doing it wrong.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you saying that you are drawing a flat plane, and when that plane is perpendicular to the camera it is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

The triangle strip you are using is infinitely thin (like a piece of paper) so when you look at it side-on it will be invisible.  It is a 2D object in a 3D world.

Drawing only two strips will not solve the issue as you will just end up with 2 2D objects.

You need to make it a volume rather than an area - like creating a cube rather than a square.  So you would need six triangle strips.

You should be able to stitch the six triangle strips together to make one long triangle strip which will make it more efficient to render.

Comment: Turned out the issue was with very large coordinates and Float's limitation handling those. Problem solved by scaling down coordinates. Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer!